# How can I get the Stockpiler achievement in Hexdefense for Android?

Tags: hexdefense

How do you get the Stockpiler? It seems impossible to "complete eight waves without spending a cent". Do you use no towers or just use the ones given?

Comment: Hi there.  I've added the game tag and changed your title a bit; if this isn't the name of the achievement, please edit the proper name in.

Answer (score 1):

I got it the first time on level 32: Slow Em Down, but I've gotten a on a few others now.  I get it after I've covered every available cell with towers and completely upgraded them.  At that point I have nothing left to spend my money on, but I'll still be able to plow through a several more waves.